# append text at the end of a line in a file pure c code

Tags: c, file-io

I need to append a text at the end of each line in a file. I have the following code:

```
FILE *tmp_copy = tmpfile();
file = fopen ( argv[2], "rw" );    
if ((file != NULL )) {
    char line [ 128 ]; /* or other suitable maximum line size */
    while( ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, file ) != NULL ))  {
       fputs(line, tmp_copy);
    }
    fclose ( file );

        rewind(tmp);
        char *p;
      /* Reopen file now with write permissions */
        fopen(argv[2], "w");
        while (( p = fgets(line, 1024, tmp))!=NULL) {
            //line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0'; /* Clear away newline */
            //sprintf(line, "%s %s\n", line, more);
            strcpy(line,"true");
            //fputs(line, file);
        }
fclose(file);
fclose(tmp);
            }

}
```

I ve edited my code. still not working
but it's not working. why?

Comment: http://forums.devshed.com/showpost.php?p=136468&postcount=5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you want the line to be re-written to the file again. However, you are not *writing* to the file, just appending to the data in memory. It's also really not possible to read and write files at the same time like that, you have to do it in two steps:

1. Read from original file, appending wanted text to line, and write to temporary file
2. Rename (or copy) from temporary file to the original file

**Edit:** Pseudo-ish code for my answer:

```
original_file = fopen(original_file_name, "r");
temporary_file_name = tmpnam("dummy");
temporary_file = fopen(temporary_file_name, "w");

while (fgets(line, original_file))
{
    remove_trailing_newline(line);
    strcat(line, " TRUE\n");
    fputs(line, temporary_file);
}

fclose(temporary_file);
fclose(original_file);

rename(temporary_file_name, original_file_name);
```

Comment: i have an undefined refference to remore_trailing_newline(line). Can you tell me why?

Comment: @justAngela Because it's not _real_ code, just pseudo-code to show the general principle. You have to do the real work yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the file is memory-mapped AND fgets returns a pointer to the original buffer (it doesn't. It needs to append the null.) AND strcat operates in place (it does), then you are not storing anything, only messing up some memory. Even if it did work, you would overwrite a part of the next line anyways.
You need to either

- Write to a temporary file and rename that after you close the original one (as suggested by Joachim Pileborg).
- Write into a buffer in memory and save it to the file when you are done reading.
- Read the file into memory in one go, then start reading the buffer line by line.